# CSS input change and return to normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make a warning if the input is not the same , like the example below:

```js
$data = document.getElementById("target").value = "";
$("#target").keyup(function() {
  if ($data.length > 3) {
    $("#target").css("border-color", "red");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="target" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

But it did not work, so if true then the border-color has to change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your `$data` variable into inside keyup events. Since you've add jQuery tag, I've selecting object using jQuery method too.

---

**UPDATE**

- Simplify the code

```js
$("#target").keyup(function(){
  var $data = $("#target").val();
  $("#target" ).css("border-color", $data.length > 3 ? "red" : "");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="target" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: but when I remove one letter, border-color does not return as early

Answer (score 1):

In provided example, `$data` holds `""`(empty string)

In `event-handler-function`, `this` refers to the element on which event is invoked hence `this.value` will return the `value` of the element.

```js
var $data = $("#target");
$data.val('');
$data.keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length > 3) {
    $("#target").css("border-color", "red");
  } else {
    $("#target").css("border-color", "");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="target" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

Another approach I would like to suggest is to using `jQuery.toggleClass` instead of `jQuery.css`

```js
var $data = $("#target");
$data.keyup(function() {
  $("#target").toggleClass('error', this.value.length > 3);
});
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="target" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks @Rayon, yes it's running, but when I remove one letter, border-color does not return as early